# What type of insect is this in my pantry?

Tags: pest-control

Found hundreds of these in the pantry. What is this?

[image]

---

[image]

More pictures here. They are really small.

[image]

Comment: no idea what they are called, but they arrive to your house in cereal products, such as flour or rolled oats

Comment: Use the [edit] link to update your question if you want to add new information. Do not post it in the space for answers.

Comment: a vacuum cleaner is your best friend for these ... also examine every unsealed item in the pantry, especially anything made from grain

Comment: Jus re-read the post, did a double take... you found *hundreds* of these? geeezzz.... yah, get in there with a vacuum at the very least. Maybe call an exterminator.

Answer (score 3):

They look like flour beetles.
They've likely gotten into your rice, grain or flour and all that will need to be removed.  Try keeping pantry grains in plastic or glass airtight containers.
Be careful with pesticides if you go that route, since it will be near your food

Comment: They are red flour beetles, or dumb flour beetles (actual name). OP should dispose of all unsealed grain products, vacuum and wipe entire pantry.

Comment: @Matthew with the addition of a reference, that would be a great stand-alone answer.